# SHBrowseForFolder doesn't work for network selection in win7

Tags: shell, visual-c++

I use SHBrowseForFolder in my code. It works well in XP. But I find it dose not run well in Windows 7 with the same code. When I click a network, it does nothing. But it can expand in XP.    By the way, I have the permission to access the network of another computer and I try accessing the resource with explorer, it's OK!

Can anyone tell me how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it is the help you wanted, but I found this on the function's [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762115%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> For Windows Vista or later, it is
>   recommended that you use IFileDialog
>   with the FOS_PICKFOLDERS option rather
>   than the SHBrowseForFolder function.
>   This uses the Open Files dialog in
>   pick folders mode and is the preferred
>   implementation.

Comment: Thanks, I will try later.

But I want to find a solution that can run my app under XP and also later windows.

Comment: I believe IFileDialog works well in XP. It's SHBrowseForFolder that doesn't work in newer systems.

Comment: Thanks! but even it works in Win7, but this function is not support in XP.

It's that any api that support both?  Thanks

Comment: FileDialog works in XP, and even in 98, if I recall correctly.

Comment: `IFileDialog` was introduced in Vista, it didn't exist in XP and earlier.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
BROWSEINFO bi;  
// ..... omit oters
bi.ulFlags = /*BIF_DONTGOBELOWDOMAIN |*/ BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS | BIF_NEWDIALOGSTYLE;
```

I add one more flag BIF_BROWSEFORCOMPUTER to the ulFlags

Answer (score 0):

There is a mixup here of the FileDialog APIs of COMMDLG and the IFileDlg interface, the latter existing in Vista and Win2008 Server only.